# How to render VueJs component based child node text?

Tags: vue.js

======Updated with more background=====

I am working on [a tool](https://www.zenuml.com) to convert text to a sequence diagram like this: [image]

In the current implementation, the code (on the left) is provisioned programmatically by calling `store.dispatch`. I would like to make it simpler for other projects to integrate. What I wanted to achieve is to create a web component: `<sequence-diagram />`. It can be used in this way:

```
// Format A
<sequence-diagram>
  response = BookController.Get(id)
  ....
</sequence-diagram>
```

The above DOM element would be rendered as a sequence diagrams (as shown on the right side of the above picture.

For the component to render properly, it needs to know what the "code" is. To pass the code (`response = ....`) to the component, I know I can use `attributes` and access it via `props` like this:

```
// Format B
<sequence-diagram code="response = ..." />
```

However, when the code is very long the above format is not as readable (imagine multiline code) as putting the code as child node text. If I use "Format A", how can I get the code content in my web component?

======Original question=====

What I want to implement is like this:

```
<my-component>
  some text
</my-component>
```

I have managed to make it work by using attributes:

```
<my-component code="some text" />
```

Using child node text is much more readable in my case, as the text can be very long.

In the template, it already has a child component. The current template is like

```
<div> <myChildComponent/> </div>
```

I don't need to keep the text in the result dom.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone how to implement it?

Comment: Added more background, hopefully it makes more sense now. @LawrenceCherone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want are slots. (See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Content-Distribution-with-Slots).

The code of your component would look like this:

```html
<div>
    <slot></slot>
    <myChildComponent/>
</div>
```

---

#### A runnable example

Below we have an `alert-box` component that displays an error message inside a `<div>` styled with a red background. This is how we use it:

```html
<alert-box> This email address is already in use. </alert-box>
```

And it generates HTML that looks like this:

```html
<div>
    <strong>Error!</strong>
    This email address is already in use.
</div>
```

---

See it in action:

```js
Vue.component('alert-box', {
  template: `
    <div class="demo-alert-box" style="background-color: red; color: white;">
      <strong>Error!</strong>
      <slot></slot>
    </div>
  `
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app"
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <alert-box> This email address is already in use.  </alert-box>
  <p> I'm a normal paragraph. </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I think you are right. However, I cannot make it work with web component as built target. I have asked that in a different question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58353854.